# I am confuse reactjs component design

Tags: reactjs

How do I or what is the alternative method to break this layout into react component? The code below is bootstrap 4 for simplicity and what I want to achieve is something like this https://codedthemes.com/demos/admin-templates/material-able/bootstrap/default/ where contents are dynamic which is actually consist of different components. So what I am showing here is the simplified HTML code of the actual thing but has a similar structure. The question here how do I break them into components with this HTML structure? Many thanks in advance and appreciate any helps. Thanks again.

```
<div class="wholepage">
    <navbar>

    </navbar>
    <sidebar>
        <dynamiccontent>
        </dynamiccontent>

    <sidebar>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it needs more clarity but it is difficult to put it in written words but I will try my best. Based on this structure, normally it may require 4 components as wholepage, Navbar, Sidebar and dynamic content. but the question is it possible to nest these components in the App.js. Usually the App.js would like this. <wholepage/> ,<navbar/> and so on..

Comment: I'm not quit sure I get what your problem is, are you asking how react works? How you create components? If yes, you should look at the getting started or some tutorials. If no and any of the existing answers don't help you, please clarify :)

Comment: I have managed to solve it. please refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023014/calling-a-component-based-on-conditions

Comment: Ah, well, next time mention you want to render something **conditionally** :D. Quite an important detail.

Comment: hi  Elias, I am also confused as to how am I put it in written words and I am not sure is it possible. Thanks again

Comment: I just went by trial and error. bit by bit.

Comment: Glad you found your solution @Nat :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is one of the selling points of React - the ability to modularise bits of code into what React calls components.

To build something like what you have linked you would need to nest components.
Using the example you might have an `app.js` that looks something like this.

```
import React from 'react'
import graph1 from './components/graph1'
import graph2 from './components/graph2'

const app = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <graph1 key1="props data goes here"/>
            <graph2 key1="props data goes here"/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default app;
```

graph1 and graph2 are seperate components that have been imported and then nested in the `app` component as shown below.

The key1 attributes in each component accept values/functions that are passed down to graph1 and graph2 components for further processing and/or display. This is what allows you to make the content dynamic.

What I've mentioned above is very rudimentary but I think answers your question. ReactJS is a massive topic and will take a lot of practice to get used to. is well documented and there is a lot of fantastic documentation, examples and discussion online such as:

- [React components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)
- [React Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)
- [React Design Patterns](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/react-design-patterns/)

DISCLAIMER: Fairly new to react myself, just trying to share the knowledge :)

Comment: hi daniel, I have managed to solve it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023014/calling-a-component-based-on-conditions. thanks