# Calling a component based on conditions

Tags: reactjs

how do call the Test component if it does not meet certain condition else call the Login component?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Test/>
      <Login/>            
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my Test component:

```
const Test = () => {
    return (
      <div id="pcoded" className="pcoded">
        <div className="pcoded-overlay-box" />
        <div className="pcoded-container navbar-wrapper">
        <Navbar/>
          <div className="pcoded-main-container">
            <div className="pcoded-wrapper">                 
                <Sidebar/>   
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Content}/>
                    <Route exact path="/content" component={Content}/>
                    <Route exact path="/contenttwo" component={ContentTwo}/>
                  </Switch>           
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    )
}

export default Test
```

many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 const Conditional = () => {
        if (conditionalVar) {
            return (

               <Test/>
            )
        } else {
            return (

                <Login/>
            )
        }
    }
    function App(){
        return(
            <div>
                {Conditional()}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UseState and function to change the condition

```
function App() {
  const [condition, setCondition] = useState("");
  // you can attach the function to a button or something
const functionToChangeCondition =(value) => {
 setCondition(value)
}

  return (
    <div>
      { condition === 'conditionA' && <Test/>}
      { condition === 'conditionB' && <login/>}
              
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your question is too ambiguous though because we are stating where the condition would be coming from. You may need to use props or it might be a condition change within the same component

Comment: hi Udendu Abasili, so sorry for the ambiguity. I want to test the presence of a login token, if is not present then go to the Login component else the Test component. Thanks

Comment: where would you be storing the token? is in the cookie, local storage or session storage

Comment: using nodejs to generate a httponly cookie. Thanks Udendu Abasili

Comment: you cannot access httponly cookie directly in the browser. That is the point of it being http only. The cookie is meant to checked by the backend (node) not the browser.